# Should consumer electronics have low voltage isolation?

Tags: isolation, ac-dc

I am making a MCU (PIC12) controlled 230V relay system. They will be operated from 230V mains. Should I use isolation (1:1 transformer?). I would use [this converter](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/3200572.pdf) for 230VAC-5VDC (or something like it - I need it to power MCU and relays coils). Or can I just simply connect it directly? I would like to make it accordingly to EU regulation or at least safe(ish) for users (me).

Would this device require isolation (or extra safety considerations)?

Comment: If there are connections the user could touch, you  need isolation. Otherwise no. Eg, my WiFi lightbulb does not have an isolated power supply as there is nothing conductive a user could touch.

Comment: Yes, it will be in box (metal) - so probably I should only ground the box itself?

Comment: Normally, yes you’d ground the metal box.

Comment: Low voltage and high should be separated, air gap or empty space on PCB is enough. Metal enclosure should be grounded if it is high voltage in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would use this converter for 230VAC-5VDC

These are cheap but they don't include the input/output EMI filters and high voltage cap. I like [potted AC-DC power supplies](https://recom-power.com/pdf/Powerline_AC-DC/RAC02-GA.pdf) from Meanwell, Recom, etc (preferably not aliexpress) as these include all the necessary bits. You only need to add the fuse and the MOV.

> Should I use isolation (1:1 transformer?).

No, the AC-DC power supply is already isolated and rates for class II.

IMO non-isolated AC power supplies are a waste of time in DIY projects, especially if you intend to plug the micro's programming connector to a PC.

> I would like to make it accordingly to EU regulation or at least safe(ish) for users (me).

If you DIY, in my opinion you should make it much safer than mandatory because regulation is mostly meant to protect the user, not the guy who's going to stick a scope probe in it.

Primary-secondary creepage distance is important.

If you use a metal box, you should definitely Earth it unless you're confident enough to build it to class II. If you use a plastic box then nope, but you can still Earth the GND on the secondary side, especially if you have low voltage wires from your microcontroller to buttons or other stuff that's accessible to the user.

When you're both the user, designer, debugger, etc, IMO it's important to make it non-deadly. That includes having as little exposed mains voltage metal as possible: for example using shrouded connectors that don't come off the board on their own, isolated spade connectors, or these [very convenient wagos](https://fr.farnell.com/wago/256-401/bloc-de-jonction/dp/4015381). Or little details like not having vertical resistors sticking out on the high voltage side, proper mounting with standoffs so it stays put when you probe it... definitely spend the extra 5c for a heat sink insulator if you have a triac... Tape a piece of insulating foil (also known as "photocopy transparent") on the live parts of the bottom of the PCB, that kind of stuff.

Comment: Yes, I though about all-in-one converters too. So class 2 means isolated?

Comment: Class 2 means double-insulated, ie extra precautions are taken to make a short from primary to unlikely enough that earthing the secondary is not mandated. Usually this is done with an insulating strip wound on the transformer core between primary and secondary coils, plus various requirements on distance, heat shrink on mains wires, etc.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appliance_classes) has some background.

Regulations vary, so if you're doing something for sale it's your responsibility to make sure that your stuff conforms.

For me, I usually build stuff that's single-insulated (i.e., one failure could lead to the case being connected to 120V) but with a metallic case that's grounded.  In such construction, that "one failure" causes a short from ground to 120V, a fuse blows, and no one is shocked by anything other than the smell of burnt fuse.  This implies that you have grounded outlets, and you're sure they're *really* grounded.

Lots of electrical appliances are doubly-insulated, meaning that there have to be *two* failures before a user ends up touching a live part.  There's a lot of ways to achieve this, but a typical way is to have a single-insulated circuit inside a plastic case, with all plastic knobs and switch handles.